# More clarifications please regarding prisma queries

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

I ma learning Prsima. And since I am not working in domain, stackoverflow is literally the only place where I can post some question that none of my actual colleagues/friends could answer.

I learned by some tutorials that we can query the database by simply initiate an instance and assign a result to a variable as the example bellow:

```
//initialise the db initiation

const user = prisma.user.find()... etc
```

However, on the documentation I find the following code:

```
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client')

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

async function main() {
  // ... you will write your Prisma Client queries here
}

main()
  .then(async () => {
    await prisma.$disconnect()
  })
  .catch(async (e) => {
    console.error(e)
    await prisma.$disconnect()
    process.exit(1)
  })
```

They disconnect the database after each query. What is wrong with the first approach and what are the advantages of the second approach? I know that using plain mysql library in nodejs you must pay attention to the opened connections. But I don't understand prisma I want to learn to do the things right.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the connection is never closed unless the NodeJS process is terminated (e.g. with CTRL + C), thus for small scripts where one single query is supposed to be executed it makes sense to then close the connection afterwards. For a long running server process it makes sense to just use one connection everywhere (or multiple if needed).

Comment: so I should not take to much attention to connection pllos?

Comment: No, usually you don't need to disconnect, or only once in a global shutdown handler if you need to shutdown gracefully.